# Using PHPUnit, How Do You Test Only Two or More Groups?

Tags: php, testing

In PHPUnit's help it displays the following:

```
  --group ...              Only runs tests from the specified group(s).
  --exclude-group ...      Exclude tests from the specified group(s).
```

Easy enough for one group.  This works:

```
phpunit --group fast
```

Now, I can't quite figure out how to do this with more than one group.  The following is not working for me:

```
phpunit --group fast unit   # It believes you want to test unit.php
phpunit --group fast, unit  # It believes you want to test unit.php
phpunit --group "fast unit" # It looks for a single group "fast unit"
phpunit --groups fast, unit # There is no option, groups
phpunit --group fast --group unit   # Only one is honored
```

Any thoughts on the correct syntax would be welcome.  Thank you.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use comma separation without any whitespace.  E.g.

```
phpunit --group fast,unit
```

Comment: This is - and I believe also intended by Phpunit's author, what POSIX normally suggests first. That is a comma so separate values inside an argument. Alternative a space (don't forget to quote the argument then), but in case of `phpunit` spaces are not supported but said commas.

Answer (score 7):

Try `phpunit --group "fast, unit"` or `phpunit --group fast,unit`.

Command-line parameters are split on space, so you have to either wrap the value in double quotes or omit spaces.

Comment: It looks like --group "fast, unit" only uses the fast group.  Thanks for the response though; your 2nd method worked great.

Comment: Quotes useful for when a group has spaces in it, for example when PHPdoc `@author` tags are converted to a group by PHPunit, you can specify one in quotes and some without e.g. `phpunit --group "Your Name <your@email.com",fast,unit` etc

Answer (score 0):

In case you use phpunit and specify a directory, the `--exclude-group` option needs to come before the directory name. E.g.:

`phpunit --exclude-group GroupA,GroupB,GroupC YOUR_DIRECTORY`

Comment: That applies to every argument, not just `--exclude-group`